# what is issue in this simple login

Tags: android

i am creating simple login page.
but when i click on sign in, my program just shutdown.
actually when i use if condition it is creating this problem. i tried if condition in different ways but not getting exact results
what is the issue?
main activity coding

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
Button a1;
EditText e1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    a1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    a1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String user=e1.getText().toString();
    if(user=="abc123"){
        Intent k=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(k);
    }
    }

 }
```

xml coding is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "my program just shutdown" indicates that you should add a Stacktrace to this question.

Comment: also, `user=="abc123"` will never work

Comment: Seems you have crash in class `MainActivity1`

Comment: String user=e1.getText().toString(); statement must be returning null, so make a check if it's null or not then proceed

Comment: then i also tried this
    user.equals("abc123")
but still not working

Comment: Did you declare `MainActivity1` in your manifest ?

Comment: if you have any exceptions then show the logcat here..

Comment: and also check your mainactivity1.java exists in maanifest or not..

Comment: yes mainactivity1 exists and also when i do not use if condition and click on sign in, it jumps from mainactivity to mainactivity1 properly , problem is in use of if statement ...
but i am unable to get it...

Comment: @user3193299 Post your stacktrace/logcat here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write:

```
String user=e1.getText().toString();
String uName = "abc123";
if(user.equals(uName.trim()){
Intent k=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
startActivity(k);
```

}

Comment: check it and also if not success then show your logcat.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use == to compare string, == is compare their address and equals is compare their value so that you need use equals
this code can provide NPE

```
if("abc123".equals(user)){
    Intent k=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
    startActivity(k);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use user.equals("abc123")

Instead of : user=="abc123"

Its Working!

Comment: i tried it but still not working

Comment: Debug it! Put Logs or Breakpoints. What's happening ?? Any Error ??

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
String user=e1.getText().toString();
    if(user=="abc123"){
        Intent k=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(k);
```

use this one

```
String user=e1.getText().toString();
String name = "abc123";
if(user.equals(name.trim())
{
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
startActivity(i);
```